# PHP 7 SQLSRV driver doesn't load

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, xampp, sqlsrv

I been trying to connect to my local MSSQL database using php. 
Right now I am stuck at installing the correct drivers for php to work with MSSQL.

SO far I have:

1.Downloaded and setup Xampp
2.Downloaded the the SQLSRV driver at:https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v4.3.0
3.Placed the files within my extension_dir and double checked php.ini varible to point to the correct folder.
4. Manually added
`extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll`
to the list of extension within php.ini.

Yet I am still seeing the same Fatal error and a boolean checking if the driver has been loaded returns false:

```
bool(false) 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in
C:\xampp\htdocs\firsttest\api.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\firsttest\api.php on line 9
```

Did I miss a step?   I have been following different guidelines and some of them seemed outdated.   I tried installing ODBC driver and the installer said that I had a higher version. Therefore I expect that shouldn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 2):

By double checking everything I realize that Xampp always install as a 32-bit application. Therefore i should've taken the 86-bit version of the .dll files instead of the 64-bit. 
Atleast this solved the problem for me.